# Why is my code showing the error - 'integer number too large'; although i had already declared the argument type as long?

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing, long-integer

```
class Fox{

    long phone_number;

    public Fox(long num){
        this.phone_number = num;
    }
}
```

```
public class Box{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fox object = new Fox(88888888888888888);
        System.out.println(object.phone_number);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`88888888888888888` is an `int` literal (that's the default type for integral literals when no suffix is specified), and it's too large for an `int`. Use `88888888888888888L` or `88888888888888888l` for a `long` literal.

Comment: thanks . that helps...